# How to display date in yyyy:MM:dd format in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, date

I work with jsp  and I want to display date in this format for example :

**2013:08:18**

I try with this code :

```
<%= new java.util.Date().getDay()+ ":" +new java.util.Date().getMonth()+":"+new java.util.Date().getYear() %>
```

but when test I have this format :

**4:11:113**

tha same think for hour :

I want to have this format :

**09:30:15**

I try with this code :

```
<%= new java.util.Date().getHours()+ ":" +new java.util.Date().getMinutes()+":"+new java.util.Date().getSeconds() %>
```

but when I test I have this format :

**10:6:26**

Comment: Seaching for "jsp date" would expose many other questions and answers on this topic.

Comment: Why colons on a date? Colons indicate a time in all four corners of the world, don't they?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format you Date reference.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"); 
sdf.format(new Date());
```

Output

```
2013:12:26 15:31:26
```

Don't use these `java.util.Date().getDay()` , `java.util.Date().getMonth()` etc. methods because these are [deprecated from Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#method).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use a SimpleDateFormat to format the date already in your Java application, store it as an attribute and reference it in the JSP via ${...}. Even better, read about and start using Joda-time if you want to prevent all kind of silly mistakes one tends to make with the java.util.Date and Calender classes.

Comment: @MichaelT Just the javadoc of SimpleDateFormat, easily fond with Google.